android widget item click in remote view service delays app open
I have a widget that has a grid view within it. In which I use RemoteViewService and set click listener using setOnClickFillInIntent and setPendingIntentTemplate, but problem is when I click the widget item after app completely destroyed, it takes 2-3 seconds to open the app. It doesn't open app directly
setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.root_linear, getOnFavoriteClickIntent())

//
private fun getOnFavoriteClickIntent(
        favorite: TemplateUiModel
    ): Intent {
        val extras = Bundle().apply {
            putString(EXTRA_ACTION, EXTRA_ITEM_CLICK_ACTION)
            putSerializable(EXTRA_ITEM, favorite)
        }

        val fillInIntent = Intent().apply {
            putExtras(extras)
        }

        return fillInIntent
    }

and below is pending intent template
private fun setOnItemClickIntent() {
        val favoriteOnItemClickIntent = Intent(applicationContext, TemplateOperationsWidgetProvider::class.java)
        favoriteOnItemClickIntent.action = ON_ITEM_CLICK_ACTION

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            applicationContext, REQUEST_CODE_FAVORITE_ITEM, favoriteOnItemClickIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        rootView.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.gvFavorites, pendingIntent)

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetIds, rootView)
    }

